# Creating Dynamic Weapons in Unreal Engine?

Tags: unreal-4

Back Story: Learning Unreal Engine 4 from scratch, I am making a fantasy Darksouls-ish Game.

I am Having trouble understanding Creating a weapon and allowing the character to hold it with added Functions. 
For example, I want to have a working torch, lights, flame, stick, to appear in his hand at the press of a button.

I do not know if I am going about this in the correct way, but this is what I did:

1. Created a Static Mesh (Torch Stick)
2. Added The Flame and Light Source to it (Emitter & Point Light)
3. Put the Emitter and Point Light into the Torch Tree
4. Created a Socket in "Persona" in the left hand

[image]

At this point I got stuck, because the third person Blueprint. Doesn't Register my amateur Torch as an "Asset".

I watched some "Equipping Weapon tutorials" But the problem is they don't explain where their weapons came from Ex (Rifle), or if they are dynamic  (Lights or laser sights)

How am I supposed to go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These 3 functions are what you want:
[image]
The third one applies to what you are trying to do, just add the socket name and then the target is your weapon and InParent is the StaticMeshComponent. Attach Location Type should be SnapTo.

For this to work, you should make a StaticMeshComponent in your PlayerClass

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class Blue Print for Actor, Then apply Static meshes and or Emitters into it like your regularly building something, Then save it and it will be one object under class.